# Question is regarding Kyber implementation in RTL (enocode 12 algorithm)

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kyber

Hi everyone I am trying to implement the Basic skeleton of the PQC Kyber Algorithm. Until now I have obtained t=As+e and s after performing point-wise multiplication (Frequency to Time domain). Now I got stuck at encode12 algorithm which is required to obtain pk(12xnxk/8+32 bytes) and secret key(12xnxk/8 bytes). Can you please help me out with this?

So basically we have designed Kyber768 variant i.e we have t as 12-bits of 768 size array and s as 12-bits of 768  array collection. According to the algorithm, the pk should be of size 1184 and sk should be of size 1152 bytes. I have referred to this [paper's](https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/8797) implementation. Here at encode part, they have considered 24-bit data as input and 32-bit as output but they are not getting the expected key size.

Please correct me if I misunderstood the concept and provide information regarding encode12 algorithm and how that can be coded in RTL language.

[image: Key generation block]

I have referred to this block diagram to build my rtl design.